# Preventing event of link fails

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got this html on the page:

```
<a href="review.asp?sitename=webcamking#video_embed" class="tutorials" data_site="webcamking">&nbsp;&nbsp;Tutorial 1</a>
```

This jquery:

```
    $('.tutorials').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation()
       var linkText=$(this).text();
       var siteName= $(this).attr('data_site');
       alert("Test. linkText:"+linkText+". siteName:"+siteName);
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'LinkClicked', siteName, linkText]);
       //window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');

       return false;

  })
```

The problem is that the link still keeps sending me to the destination. I need to stop it. I need to check what I get with the alert..and hope the google analytics event is triggered!!

**Update: Modified code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $('.tutorials').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var linkText=$(this).text();
       var siteName= $(this).attr('data_site');
       alert("Test. linkText:"+linkText+". siteName:"+siteName);
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'LinkClicked', siteName, linkText]);
       //window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');

       return false;

  });
```

Comment: works fine for me in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kchpj/

Comment: it is a static link..yeah..no need for live()

Comment: is there a shorter way to write it..may be I should add onclick event directly to the link?!?!

Comment: put an alert as the first line of the function to make sure the code is running at all, code looks fine to me so I think it's something else (don't even think you need the stopPropagation line)

Comment: Do u mean before the e.preventDefault()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Did you enclose your jQuery code block in the `$( document ).ready( function() {})` statement?
2. Is there any piece of code above this block that is breaking down and preventing this block from executing?

Comment: I do have an error..in the javascript above..I put the code now ..at the top of the document.ready

Comment: Is it working now? Post the code block that's throwing the error. We can try and troubleshoot that as well!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

html:

```
<div id="tutorials">&nbsp;&nbsp;Tutorial 1</div>​
```

jquery:

```
 $('#tutorials').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation()
   var linkText=$(this).text();
   var siteName= $(this).attr('data_site');
   alert("Test. linkText:"+linkText+". siteName:"+siteName);
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'LinkClicked', siteName, linkText]);
   //window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');

   return false;
```

})​

Comment: nice solution...I will check it out

Comment: Do you actually want to the url review.asp?sitename=webcamking#video_embed ? with the passed data_site contents?

let me know, i will edit my sample

Comment: No thanks..I got it to work..but your alternative solution is nice